# Git: missing subdirectories after clone

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

We are in the process of switching to git for our Version Control system.
I used 'git svn' to clone my current svn repository "bigproject" to a git repository - I also setup a cron to sync svn commits to this git repo.

"bigproject" has no defined externals or svn:ignore properties
"bigproject" has many directories and sub-directories (upto 7 levels deep) like so.

```
src/apps/fld1/fld2/fld3/fld4/fld5
```

When I inspect the migrated git repo, it seems to have all the folders as expected.

Before actual migration, I setup a staging server and pushed this "bigproject" repo there, and I was trying to switch my build scripts to use git instead of svn.

This is how I hosted the repo on my "git staging" server:

```
git clone --bare bigproject/ bigproject.git
cp -R bigproject.git /opt/git/
cd /opt/git/bigproject.git
git init --bare --shared
```

On the build server, after I do a git clone and inspect, I found that some of the subdirectories were missing - esp after 3 levels deep

```
git@mygitserver:bigproject.git
```

after the clone I only have

```
src/apps/fld1
```

I tried to re-export the bare repo many times to eliminate any human errors but I can't seem to figure out.

Have any of you seen this before?

Comment: Are the directories empty? Git ignores empty directories, including directories that only contain empty directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible reasons

1) you are under Windows and have reached the 255 characters max in terms of PATH length

2) src/apps/fld1/ contains some files whereas fld2 and all its subdirectories do not contain any file. You cannot add an empty directory in Git, a directory being considered as empty if it does not contain any file. If a directory contain a subdirectory that does not contain any file, you still cannot add it to git. You can check [Git FAQ - how to add an empty diectory](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F). 
Below is an excerpt

> Can I add empty directories?
>
> Currently the design of the Git index (staging area) only permits
>   files to be listed, and nobody competent enough to make the change to
>   allow empty directories has cared enough about this situation to
>   remedy it.
>
> Directories are added automatically when adding files inside them.
>   That is, directories never have to be added to the repository, and are
>   not tracked on their own.
>
> You can say "git add " and it will add the files in there.
>
> If you really need a directory to exist in checkouts you should create
>   a file in it. .gitignore works well for this purpose (there is also a
>   tool MarkEmptyDirs using the .NET framework which allows you to
>   automate this task); you can leave it empty or fill in the names of
>   files you do not expect to show up in the directory.

Comment: spot on. I had empty directories down those paths. Thanks!